# How to import existing RunDeck projects in MySQL back to new RunDeck?

Tags: mysql, import, debian, recovery, rundeck

Had a RunDeck installation which was configured (by some one else who no longer works and made no documentation) to store all meta-data in MySQL. Both were running on different VMs.

Lost RunDeck application VM. MySQL still remains. Deployed a new RunDeck Application, and configured it to use existing MySQL. On starting it, got the following error in service.log:

> FrameworkException{message='Project does not exist: project-redis_scans', resource='FrameworkProjectMgr{name=name, baseDir=/var/rundeck/projects}'}

There are 4 projects in total which needs to be imported back into RunDeck. What is the right way?

Answer (score 0):

In the rundeck-config.properties file check if the connection url is correct

```
dataSource.dbCreate = update
dataSource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rundeck?autoReconnect=true
dataSource.username=root
rundeck.security.useHMacRequestTokens=false
```

replace localhost with ip of the VM 
also check if your new VM is able to telnet to the mysql VM on port 3306

Comment: Yes, all that is fine. The error I mentioned above shows that RunDeck is able to read MySQL and see a project (project-redis_scans) also.

Comment: You need to recover the projects folder and port it to new projects folder in the new rundeck....

Comment: The projects folder from the App VM on which RunDeck App was running is lost. Are you referring to any other folder?

Comment: Ok then it would be difficult for you to recover the present rundeck into fully operational mode. You will need to rework the whole of the project..